# PHP Is there a more efficient/faster way to query SQL and echo results?

Tags: php, html, arrays, database

I have a query that can return results up to 4000 and for the past year or so I've been using this code

> PHP - $results is array from query

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
```

Inside the above code I have it print out a table row with a bunch of table data in it. This can take up to several seconds for it to load. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Use pagination. You need to add `LIMIT` in your query. Read more - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: The table already has pagination with DataTables. If I used pagination with LIMIT, I wouldn't be able to sort unless I added about 50 lines of code.

Comment: wait, do you sort data in PHP? Why not to use mysql `ORDER BY`?

Comment: No I'm using DataTables to sort, I do not need them sorted on first query, there's tabs for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Piecing together the question and comments, it sounds like:

1. You perform the query and get $results.
2. You output HTML with formatted data from $results.
3. You use DataTables (+ jQuery) client-side (browser) to sort the results.

Change your DataTables configuration to use [serverSide](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) processing. From DataTables web site: "Server-side processing - where filtering, paging and sorting calculations are all performed by a server." Essentially, you let DataTables request chunks of data and you translate those requests into small MySQL queries with ORDER BY to match the DataTables user-selected sorting and LIMIT to match the DataTables paging. According to the DataTables web site, this can take you from the 5,000 - 50,000 row capacity on up to millions.

Comment: It's not DataTables that's a problem, it's the PHP query to the SQL database. And I can't use javascript to query the server for security reasons. I was having this long loading time problem happening before I started using DataTables and pages and such. It's just echoing a <tr>5<td> for each result is heavy on loading.

Comment: The queries are always done by PHP. The issue is whether the queries are done as one large batch or in multiple small "chunks". DataTables can work both ways. If you do it in chunks then DataTables will make an AJAX call to another PHP script to retrieve a chunk of data at a time. That is guaranteed to solve the speed problem. This should **not** be a security issue as the queries are still PHP, not Javascript. The long loading time is simply due to the amount of data being transferred at one time. Since you are already using DataTables, use it to help solve the problem.

Comment: I am just going to convert the page to use xml instead of javascript with a server side update of the xml daily in php. Data does not need to be updated in real time